# Why all my videos' thumbnail are black

Tags: android, media-player

My video player works great, but its thumbnails are black for every video format. my code is

```
public static Bitmap getVideoBitmap(String path, int widthWanted, int heightWanted) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = null;
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    try {
        retriever.setDataSource(path);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        retriever.release();
        retriever = null;
        return null;
    }

    String duration = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
    int timeUs = Integer.valueOf(duration);
    for(int i = 1; i <= timeUs; i++) {
        thumbnail = retriever.getFrameAtTime(i * 1000 * 1000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_NEXT_SYNC);
    }
    thumbnail = getWantedBitmap(thumbnail, widthWanted, heightWanted);
    return thumbnail;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say, maybe check if the final ``thumbnail`` is null, look in the log if more information are available. BTW, seems that you loop over all the frames and takes the last one, if so probably it will be black.